# Replace textbox lines contains 2 digit replace with Vbcrlf (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, winforms

if I have a textbox1.lines > how can i somehow do where there is a single digit, to be replaced with vbcrlf? (Visual Studio)

```
2
77,48
1,3
7
9
11,90
```

Output:

```
77,48
1,3


11,90
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
Dim NewLines As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

For Each Line As String In TextBox1.Lines
    If (Line.Contains(",")) Then
        NewLines.Add(Line)
    Else
        NewLines.Add("")
    End If
Next

TextBox1.Lines = NewLines.ToArray()
```

Outputs:

```
(blank line)
77,48
1,3
(blank line)
(blank line)
11,90
```

This iterates through each line in the `Lines` collection. If the line contains a comma (which indicates there is more than one letter), it adds the line to the output list. If it does not contain a comma, it adds an empty string.

Finally, the contents of the output list are assigned to the `Lines` property of the `TextBox`.

Also: There could likely be a neater Linq solution but I'm not an expert

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with a single line of code using the IEnumerable extensions

```
textBox1.Lines = textBox1.Lines.Select(Function(x) 
                 If(x.Trim.Length = 1, "", x)).ToArray()
```

where textBox1 is the name of the variable referencing your textbox.

Notice that I have added a Trim inside the expression to be sure that blank spaces are not counted in the string length. Of course if you want to preserve lines that have empty spaces at their end you could remove the Trim() call.

Comment: The OP has modified the question to change the space to a comma now, which invalidated both of our answers

Comment: Question is tagged vb.net. I believe you have replied in C#.

Comment: It's VB.NET and an empty string in the array is all that is needed for a blank line, so `TextBox1.Lines = TextBox1.Lines.Select(Function(x) If(x.Trim.Length = 1, "", x)).ToArray()`.

Comment: @Martin it doesn't change the result, it would be very different if, in a line with "1,13", we want to preserve the 1 and remove the 13.

Comment: @Steve I appreciate that but as soon as a line has a single 2+ digit number on this will not work. Just trying to be helpful rather than criticising

Comment: Perhaps we are giving different interpretations to the word _single digit_ I suppose that this includes only the numbers from 0 to 9, not numbers higher than 9. But I could be wrong or the OP has not expressed their intention clearly

Comment: that is, there will be a 2-digit number. (ie 1-14-17, completely random). not more than 100, though. the first code works well and is simple to understand, it is a little more second code complicated even if it is from a single line, I am beginner enough to be able to fully understand it. yet thank you for your help, I learn every thing, to become better.

Comment: @NardaleMoyda To explain, we know that Lines is an array. As such it could be enumerated (or better it have the required interface to be enumerated). The Select method loops over the sequence (the Lines) and for each element calls the function that we have written for the Select argument. This function checks the length of the current element in the sequence (x) and returns it or returns a space. Inside the Select loop every return value is accumulated to form the Select's return value. At this point the Select's return value is transformed in the Array required by the Lines property